# Usage of ‘a small quantity of’

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

If something was bright and it becomes less bright, Is ‘a small quantity of brightness has gone’ semantically correct?

Comment: It is not idiomatic. Brightness is measured by _level_ or _degree_, not _quantity_. "The level of brightness has decreased slightly."

Comment: @Kate Bunting But ‘quantity’ means ‘amount’ and ‘amount’ means ‘degree’ so ‘quantity’ means ‘degree’ according to dictionary?

Comment: @Kate Bunting It’s also a matter of whether it’s idiomatic or not?

Comment: I'm not sure that _amount_ does mean _degree_. _Quantity_ and _amount_ are used with material substances, and sometimes abstract nouns, but not with _qualities_ such as 'brightness' or 'loudness'. Imagine turning the knob of a dimmer switch or volume control. You  are changing the level of light or sound, not the 'quantity'.

Comment: If something was bright, and now it has become less bright, it has *dimmed*.